# Join two CSV files in Ruby without using tables

Tags: ruby, csv, data-processing

I have 2 CSV files with columns like `A, B, C`.. & `D, E, F`. I want to join these two CSV files into a new file with rows where `File1.B = File2.E` and the row would have columns `A, B/E, C, D, F`. How can I achieve this JOIN without using tables?

Comment: Post some example data and desired results

Comment: I'm not sure if I interpreted the question correctly (especially the reference to "JOIN"). If the last two lines of the second file are interchanged is the answer to remain the same? @Виктор answer corresponds to "yes"; my answer, "no".  If the second file has more than one row with a `"9"` in column `"E"`, are of those rows to be combined with the current row from the first file and written to file? Again, "yes", "no".

Comment: You are now up to 1 out of 10 in awarding the green checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Givens**

We are given the following.

The paths for the two input files:

```
fname1 = 't1.csv'
fname2 = 't2.csv'
```

The path for the output file:

```
fname3 = 't3.csv'
```

The names of the headers to match in each of the two input files:

```
target1 = 'B'
target2 = 'E'
```

I do assume that (as is the case with the example) the two files necessarily contain the same number of lines.

**Create test files**

Let's first create the two files:

```
str = [%w|A B C|, %w|1 1 1|, %w|2 2 2|, %w|3 4 5|, %w|6 9 9|].
        map { |a| a.join(",") }.join("\n")
  #=> "A,B,C\n1,1,1\n2,2,2\n3,4,5\n6,9,9"
File.write(fname1, str)
  #=> 29
```

```
str = [%w|D E F|, %w|21 1 41|, %w|22 5 42|, %w|23 8 45|, %w|26 9 239|].
        map { |a| a.join(",") }.join("\n")
  #=> "D,E,F\n21,1,41\n22,5,42\n23,8,45\n26,9,239" 
File.write(fname2, str)
  #=> 38
```

**Read the input files into `CSV::Table` objects**

When reading `fname1` I will use the `:header_converters` option to convert the header `"B"` to `"B/E"`. Note that this does not require knowledge of the location of the column with header `"B"` (or whatever it may be).

```
require 'csv'

new_target1 = target1 + "/" + target2
  #=> "B/E"

csv1 = CSV.read(fname1, headers: true,
  header_converters: lambda { |header| header==target1 ? new_target1 : header})
csv2 = CSV.read(fname2, headers: true)
```

**Construct arrays of headers to be written from each input file**

```
headers1 = csv1.headers
  #=> ["A", "B/E", "C"]
headers2 = csv2.headers - [target2]
  #=> ["D", "F"]
```

**Create the output file**

We will first write the new headers `headers1 + headers2` to the output file.

Next, for each row index `i` (`i = 0` corresponding to the first row after the header row in each file), for which a condition is satisfied, we write as a single row the elements of `csv1[i]` and `csv2[i]` that are in the columns having headers in `headers1` and `headers2`. The condition to be satisfied to write the rows at index `i` is that `i` satisfies:

```
csv1[i][new_target1] == csv2[i][target2] #=> true
```

Now open `fname3` for writing, write the headers and then the body.

```
CSV.open(fname3, 'w') do |csv|
  csv << headers1 + headers2
  [csv1.size, csv2.size].min.times do |i|
    csv << (headers1.map { |h| csv1[i][h] } +
            headers2.map { |h| csv2[i][h] }) if
             csv1[i][new_target1] == csv2[i][target2]
  end
end
  #=> 4
```

Let's confirm that what was written is correct.

```
puts File.read(fname3)
A,B/E,C,D,F
1,1,1,21,41
6,9,9,26,239
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have CSV files like these:

> first.csv:

```
A | B | C
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 2
3 | 4 | 5
6 | 9 | 9
```

> second.csv:

```
D  | E | F
21 | 1 | 41
22 | 5 | 42
23 | 8 | 45
26 | 9 | 239
```

You can do something like this:

```
require 'csv'

first = CSV.read('first.csv')
second = CSV.read('second.csv')

CSV.open("result.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << %w[A B.E C D F]
  first.each do |rowF|
    second.each do |rowS|
      csv << [rowF[0],rowF[1],rowF[2],rowS[0],rowS[2]] if rowF[1] == rowS[1]
    end
  end

end
```

To get this:

> result.csv:

```
A | B.E | C | D  | F
1 | 1   | 1 | 21 | 41
6 | 9   | 9 | 26 | 239
```

Comment: This is what I used, but I was hoping to find something better than O(mxn)

Comment: You can do better if you sort the data first and get O(max(m log m, n log n)).  You could also get O(m+n) with O(m+n) extra space if you use a hash table keyed by the column you're joining on.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use group by to create a hash table and then iterate over the keys of the hash table.  Assuming the column you're joining on is unique in each table:

```
join_column = "whatever"
csv1 = CSV.table("file1.csv").group_by { |r| r[join_column] }
csv2 = CSV.table("file2.csv").group_by { |r| r[join_column] }

joined_data = csv1.keys.sort.map do |join_column_values|
  csv1[join_column].first.merge(csv2[join_column].first)
end
```

If the column is not unique in each table, then you need to decide how you want to handle those cases since there will be more than just the first element in the arrays `csv1[join_column]` and `csv2[join_column]`.  You could do an O(mxn) join as suggested in one of the other answers (i.e. nested map calls), or you could filter or combine them based on some criteria.  The choice really depends on your usecase.